# Error in email-sending program in Python with smtplib

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("MyEmail", "pass")

msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
server.sendmail("MyEmail", "MyEmail", msg)
server.quit()
```

The error message is the following:

> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14

What is the solution to my problem?

Comment: I think you need to call "server.ehlo()" before calling server.starttls(), this is the "handshake" for the gmail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need permissions, go to this link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and allow the access